# Rectangle with rounded corners and gradient fill

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make a rectangle with rounded corners and a gradient.  I have this code:

```
import flash.geom.*;
var rect:Shape = new Shape();
rect.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x00ff00, 0); //(thickness, color, alpha)
var fillType:String = "linear";
var colors:Array = [0x000000, 0xFFFF00,0xFFFFFF];
var alphas:Array=[1,1,1];
var ratios:Array=[0,127,255];
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.createGradientBox(20, 20, 0, 0, 0);
rect.beginGradientFill(fillType, colors, alphas, ratios, matrix) : Void;
rect.graphics.drawRoundRect(720,450, 213.4, 29.1, 12, 12); 
rect.graphics.endFill();
addChild(rect);
```

I'm getting an error from this line :

```
rect.beginGradientFill(fillType, colors, alphas, ratios, matrix) : Void;
```

> 1078: Label must be simple identifier.

I'm a novice and everything I look up seems to have a bunch of terminology I don't quite understand, so please keep it simple.

I want the yellow (FFFF00) to actually be a color picked from the stage so if that can be thrown in there easily without complicating the answer to the above question, feel free.

Comment: Remove the `: Void' in line 10.

Comment: Given your level my advice would be to not post any question here but to follow at least a few really basic tutorials so you at least have a little clue about how to write AS3 code. Considering that all you've done is try to change one line of code (from something you copied and pasted) and immediately failed and posted here, you can't keep this up, make a real effort and follow a tutorial.

Comment: I thought you actually tried to write a line of code but I really think you first copied/pasted the whole thing from somewhere, then you copied/pasted the method beginGradientFill from somewhere (which is why you had the :void), then finally you copied/pasted the wrong answer that was given. So all you know so far about AS3 is copy/paste. You are wasting everybody's time here. Follow a tutorial, learn something.

Comment: thanx to everyone's advice, the code worked perfect this time.  For the ppl complaining about posting the same question twice, it was two errors in same line of which I had fixxed one then the other but never both.  Also, it isn't coppied and pasted, though Ihave C&P before, and also, this is the only question I've asked in a 400 line script (maybe not a lot for others but a lot of work for me) and only after two days of watching videos and digging through web pages. But thanx again everyone this was very helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have two errors in the same line :

```
rect.beginGradientFill(fillType, colors, alphas, ratios, matrix) : Void;
```

We use [`void`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/specialTypes.html#void) ( with lower `v`, it's not **V**oid ) to indicate the type of a function which will return nothing when we are defining it, not when calling that function.

Then [`beginGradientFill()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginGradientFill()) is a function of the `Graphics` class so it should be used with `rect.graphics` :

```
rect.graphics.beginGradientFill(fillType, colors, alphas, ratios, matrix);
```

Then your code can be like this (it's an example) :

```
var fillType:String = "linear";
var colors:Array = [0x000000, 0xFFFF00, 0xFF0000];
var alphas:Array=[1, 1, 1];
var ratios:Array=[0, 127, 255];
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.createGradientBox(200, 10, 0, 0, 0);

var rect:Shape = new Shape();
    rect.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x00ff00, 0); 
    rect.graphics.beginGradientFill(fillType, colors, alphas, ratios, matrix)
    rect.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 200, 200, 12, 12); 
    rect.graphics.endFill();
addChild(rect);
```

For more about gradient, take a look on [`Graphics.beginGradientFill()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginGradientFill()), and on [creating gradient lines and fills](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dd7.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8e525-7ffa) ...

Hope that can help.

Answer (score -1):

preface: didn't see the comment from before, but that's the correct solution.

The breakpoint is here:

```
rect.beginGradientFill(fillType, colors, alphas, ratios, matrix) : Void;
```

The function call should not have the " : Void" identifier. That's used when the function is originally written.

try this:

```
rect.beginGradientFill(fillType, colors, alphas, ratios, matrix);
```

Comment: Voted down. You cannot answer a question by giving a non working code. Obviously rect does not have a beginGradientFill method.

Comment: The code does give him some direction, and obviously removing 'Void' would put him on the right path. A novice could've found that. Please reserve your opinion-driven feedback.

Comment: It's not a matter of opinion, the code shown in your answer simply cannot work since a Shape object does not have a method called "beginGradientFill". This is correctly shown in the other answer. Fix your code or accept the correct vote down.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginGradientFill%28%29

Opinions. They don't work in Flash. Get over yourself.

Comment: Hope you don't put the same amount of stubbornness into your coding. The link you posted shows the beginGradientFill of the Graphics class. Your code is trying to call that method on a Shape instance (var rect:Shape = new Shape();). The Shape class does not have that method and your code cannot work for that reason. You want to keep ignoring that fine, but your code is still broken and has no place here. It should be rect.graphics.beginGradientFill not rect.beginGradientFill.